# How to write into an output stream with content is csv using opencsv?

Tags: java, opencsv

```
@Value("classpath:tpls/Non-PnL_Template_Export_Order_Cross_Checking.csv")
private org.springframework.core.io.Resource exportFileOrderTpl;
```

I create an output stream of a CSVWriter

```
InputStream inputStream = exportFileOrderTpl.getInputStream();

String outputFileName = "file.csv"

var fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fileOutputStream);

var outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

var writer = new CSVWriter(outputStreamWriter)

String [] rows = {"1","2","3"}
writer.writeNext(rows);

var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
```

But my `outputStream` is empty. How to fix it!. Thank you

Comment: `writer` was opened on what…?

Comment: @g00se: I updated on my question, my missing sr.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with those last two lines but I don't see `writer` being closed

Comment: Which is the final destination (`file.csv`) ? How many output-sinks do you have (`fileOutputStream`, `outputStreamWriter`, `writer`, `outputStream`) ? Please research via [search `[opencsv] write csv` here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencsv%5D%20write%20csv) and on a [tutorial for OpenCSV](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv#2-the-csvwriter).

Comment: Might help to arrange your code in _coherent_ blocks (to group logical what belongs together) ... right now all statements are separated by blank lines which makes them appear"randomly choosen" 

Comment: @hc_dev: CSVWriter will create a file .csv on my local machine, I'm wanting using output stream to no need create a file .csv on my machine. So any method support for this ?

Comment: `try(var writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFileName),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) { ... }`
` is what I'd do

Comment: @Loint, Then update your question and explain there what you want, e.g. ask "How to use CSVWriter's output without needing a file?" Then answer could be [`StringWriter` for obtaining a String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) or [`PrintWriter` for connecting to some required output-stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) as text-based output passed to CSVWriter.

Answer (score 0):

### Your issues

#### Not closing streams

The data like your `rows` is written to a buffer (in `outputStreamWriter`). Once you flush or close the stream(-writer), it gets piped.

#### Too much streams/sinks

You just created an empty `outputStream` and then (a) write it to another, (b) checking if it is empty. Does that make sense?

```java
var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
```

At this point you could check your only used final sink `fileOutputStream` for bytes that have gotten flushed.

#### Combining two inputs

From your code, you want to combine two inputs into one output (stream or file). So you are connecting the `CSVWriter` to an already filled outputStream

```java
// create final output file and connect a stream as sink: fileOutputStream
String outputFileName = "file.csv"
var fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

// copy first input from given CSV file to sink: fileOutputStream
InputStream inputStream = exportFileOrderTpl.getInputStream();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fileOutputStream);

// connect additional CSV input to sink: fileOutputStream
var outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
var writer = new CSVWriter(outputStreamWriter)

// write rows via CSV to sink: fileOutputStream
String [] rows = {"1","2","3"}
writer.writeNext(rows);

// close writer including connected streams: fileOutputStream
writer.close();
```

### Writing CSV-file using OpenCSV

Like in [Baeldungs introduction to OpenCSV's `CSVWriter`](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv#2-the-csvwriter), you could use the method in given example and slightly modify to write, your single row or many rows to a specified file path:

```java
public void writeRows(List<String[]> stringArray, Path path) throws Exception {
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(path.toString()));
    for (String[] array : stringArray) {
        writer.writeNext(array);
    }
    
    writer.close();
}

// define your rows consisting of many columns
String[] rowA = {"1","2","3"}
String[] rowB = {"3","4","5"}
List<String[]> rows = List.of(rowA, rowB);

// define your output file
String outputFileName = "file.csv";
Path outputPath = Paths.get(outputFileName);

// write the rows to file by calling the method
writeRows(rows, outputPath)
```

Note: Only the `writer` is used as output-sink. Everything IO-related is handled by OpenCSV. No separate output-streams needed.